# Cython how to make multidimensional string matrix?

Tags: cython

Cython how to make multidimensional string matrix?any one knows?Thanks
I have below code but not work:

```
def make_matrix(size_t nrows, size_t ncols):
    cdef char *mat = <char*>malloc(nrows * ncols * sizeof(char))
    cdef char[:, ::1] mv = <char[:nrows, :ncols]>mat
    cdef cnp.ndarray arr = np.asarray(mv)
    return arr
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you want an array `nrows` strings, each `ncols` long you can just do:

```
np.zeros((nrows,),dtype=('S',ncols))
```

This creates an empty numpy array of the format you want, and there's no need to invoke specialised Cython features.

The good reason not to attempt to do it in Cython using `malloc` is that the memory will never get freed (so you'll have a memory leak unless you free the memory yourself). It's very hard to know when you need to free it.

---

As an alternative (if you genuinely do need `malloc` for some reason) you could work with `int8` instead, which is the same size as a `char` and should be interconvertable.